# How to improve the execution time of this function?

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, optimization, fft

Suppose that `f(x,y)` is a bivariate function as follows:

```
function [ f ] = f(x,y)
    UN=(g)1.6*(1-acos(g)/pi)-0.8;
    f= 1+UN(cos(0.5*pi*x+y));
end
```

How to improve execution time for function `F(N)` with the following code:

```
function [VAL] = F(N)
x=0:4/N:4;
y=0:2*pi/1000:2*pi;
VAL=zeros(N+1,3);
for i = 1:N+1
    val = zeros(1,N+1);
    for j = 1:N+1
        val(j) = trapz(y,f(0,y).*f(x(i),y).*f(x(j),y))/2/pi;
    end
    val = fftshift(fft(val))/N;
    l = (length(val)+1)/2;
    VAL(i,:)= val(l-1:l+1);
end
VAL = fftshift(fft(VAL,[],1),1)/N;
L = (size(VAL,1)+1)/2;
VAL = VAL(L-1:L+1,:);
end
```

Note that `N=2^p` where `p>10`, so please consider the memory limitations while optimizing the code using `ndgrid`, `arrayfun`, etc.

FYI: The code intends to find the central 3-by-3 submatrix of the `fftn` of

```
fun=@(a,b) trapz(y,f(0,y).*f(a,y).*f(b,y))/2/pi;
```

where `a,b` are in `[0,4]`. The key idea is that we can save memory using the code above specially when `N` is very large. But the execution time is still an issue because of nested loops. See the figure below for `N=2^2`:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to execute this code? It seems to me that the function will crash since `f` is not defined inside the function and not passed by any argument.

Comment: Have you run the profiler yet? Which line is taking the most time (note: if you cannot share `f()`, we cannot run the profiler for you)? In general, though, there is a trade-off between memory and speed - you can be fast or use little memory; if you want to be both, you may be forced to rethink the algorithm.

Comment: @patrik As mentioned first, `f(x,y)` is an arbitrary bivariate function. You can suppose `f(x,y)=x+y`. Regardless of `f(x,y)`, can you optimize the code?

Comment: @Jonas Nested loops are slow. I want to substitute them fully or partially with another code increasing the speed while preserving memory efficiency. You can suppose `f(x,y)=x+y` here. But I do not expect a special trick for a special `f(x,y)'. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @AmirKazemi [trapz](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html) can take vectors, but `f` is not a bivariate function. `f` is **undefined**. If you runs the code it will crash, since `f` is undefined. It is important everything that you want to demonstrate is correct. If something is left out the code is obviously not tested and then there is no guarantee that it will work even if `f` would be defined. The comment was to make you aware of the problems in your code and make you edit and test it. I will not help to optimize buggy code. Please show that you have done some effort first.

Comment: @AmirKazemi Also, it feels like you tries to do some kind of convolution here but with a twist. There has been a lot of research on this, which means this can be done quite efficiently. You may want to check the function `conv2` and see if your code can be modified to work with this function. You can also check `conv`. This one can probably replace your `trapz` and some more code with a faster and simpler approach. You may also want to consider using a much smaller "window" for the convolution, when you optimize. In general the values far from "t" in the convolution will have a limited impact.

Comment: @patrik Thanks for your time and comments. I have just added `f(x,y)`. Please do not hesitate to let me know if you think the problem is not clear. To the best of my knowledge, I am not doing a convolution. I want to do `fftn` in an efficient way, because I do not need all the arrays `fftn` gives, but a central submatrix of it, here a 3-by-3 one.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, but some possibly helpful hints:

0) The trivial: Are you sure you need numerics? Can't you do the computation analytically?

1) Do not use function handles:

```
function [ f ] = f(x,y)
    f= 1+1.6*(1-acos(cos(0.5*pi*x+y))/pi)-0.8
end
```

2) Simplify analytically: `acos(cos(x))` is the same as `abs(mod(x + pi, 2 * pi) - pi)`, which should compute slightly faster. Or, instead of sampling and then numerically integrating, first integrate analytically and sample the result.

3) The FFT is a very efficient algorithm to compute the full DFT, but you don't need the full DFT. Since you only want the central 3 x 3 coefficients, it might be more efficient to directly apply the [DFT definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition) and evaluate the formula only for those coefficients that you want. That should be both fast and memory-efficient.

4) If you repeatedly do this computation, it might be helpful to precompute DFT coefficients. Here, `dftmtx` from the Signal Processing toolbox can assist.

5) To get rid of the loops, think about the problem not in the form of computation instructions, but a single matrix operation. If you consider your input N x N matrix as a vector with N² elements, and your output 3 x 3 matrix as a 9-element vector, then the whole operation you apply (numerical integration via `trapz` and DFT via `fft`) appears to be a simple linear transform, which it should be possible to express as an N² x 9 matrix.